# What is the best practice to handle invalid or illegal combinations of inputs in a verilog module?

Tags: verilog

When I am writing a module for a bigger project that takes several control input, what is the best practice/standard to handle combinations of input that are invalid or illegal?

For example, I have a Queue that has three control signals - `Enqueue`, `Dequeue` and `Delete`. Assume that only one of the operations can be performed in a cycle. Therefore, only one input signals should be asserted at a time. Now, what is the proper way to handle the case when some parent module drives two control signals at a time?

In my project, I can handle it any way I wish and I will take care to avoid it. But in a company wide level, someone may mess up later and use it improperly. What is the practice to prevent this problem? Or in other words, I am looking for something analogous to `try-catch/exception` in `verilog`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic example of where an *assertion* is useful. We don't tend to put error-checking logic in our chips (unless we are designing something safety-critical); instead we use assertions. A *property* is a potential fact about your design (eg "only one input signal *is* asserted at a time"). An *assertion* is a statement that a property *should be true*.

You can check assertions either using a formal tool or by simulating. In your case, the latter makes sense. So, you would implement a suitable check (the assertion) and then would run all your simulations and make sure that the assertion never fails.

So, how to implement the assertion? How to code it? You could

i) Switch to SystemVerilog. SystemVerilog has an `assert` statement that is useful for basic assertions and there is a part of SystemVerilog called [*SystemVerilog Assertions* (SVA)](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/assertions/), which is much more powerful. Verilog is merely a subset of SystemVerilog, but nevertheless switching is still clearly easier said than done - you might need a change in company policy or to buy more expensive licences or some training...

ii) Write assertions in some other language (eg SVA or [PSL](http://www.doulos.com/knowhow/psl/), but code in Verilog. Again, easier said than done - again you might need a change in company policy or to buy more expensive licences or some training..

iii) Use [OVL](http://accellera.org/activities/working-groups/ovl). This is a free, downloadable library of modules that implement basic (and not so basic) assertions. There is a version written in Verilog, so no company policy change or licences required, but you'd have to invest a bit of time learning how to use them.

iv) Write assertions in Verilog. You could hide them inside generate statements (or ifdefs if you must), to keep them away from the synthesiser, eg:

```
generate if (ASSERTIONS_ENABLED)
  begin : ASSERT_ONLY_ONE_OF_Enqueue_Dequeue_Delete
    always @(posedge clock)  // it is nearly always better to check assertions synchronously
      if (Enqueue + Dequeue + Delete > 2'b1) 
        $display("ASSERTION FAIL : ASSERT_ONLY_ONE_OF_Enqueue_Dequeue_Delete");
  end
endgenerate
```

(The links to SVA and PSL are to my company's website. But these were first in the Google results, anyway.)